# trouble connecting to dashDB on BlueMix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

Here is my code of my .php app connecting to dash-DB instance

```
    //parse VCAP_SERVICES Environment variable
    $vcap_services = $_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"];
    $services_json = json_decode($vcap_services,true);
    $sqldb = $services_json["dashDB"];
    if (empty($sqldb)) {
        echo "No sqldb service instance is bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance";
    return;
}

//Get Credentials object (db,host,port,username,password)
$sqldb_config = $services_json["dashDB"][0]["credentials"];

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $sqldb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $sqldb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $sqldb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $sqldb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $sqldb_config["password"].
   ";";


$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', ''); //db connection

$sql = "SELECT * FROM BX1_USERS WHERE Username ='$username'";
$foundElements = 0;

if ($conn) {
   $stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql, array('cursor' => DB2_SCROLLABLE));
//lLINE 44 that the output.txt fiel referres to starts here
       while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
           $dbusername = $row['Username'];
       $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
       $dbfirstname = $row['FirstName'];
       $dblastname = $row['LastName']; 
       $foundElements = 1;
   }
}

print $foundElements;
echo "<br>";
print $sql;
echo "<br>";

    if ($foundElements == 1){
 /// rest of my code here
```

I tested the printed $sql in the database console and it works just fine.. .. but still $foundElements = 0 ...

I get this error in the recent logs file:

"
PHP Warning:  db2_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/vcap/app/www/login.php on line 44,
"

I even added this to the code:

```
print $sqldb_config["db"];
echo "<br>";
print $sqldb_config["host"];
echo "<br>";
print $sqldb_config["port"];
echo "<br>";
print $sqldb_config["username"];
echo "<br>";
print $sqldb_config["password"];
```

and the page show the same exact values as in my VCAP.

Comment: I added this to my code:
     if (empty($stmt)) {
            echo "Statement is empty" ;
        }
and the page DOES echo that message... so the $stmt seems to be empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few hours of banging my head against the wall I found an answer.

the code I was using was from a connection and queries I used on the IBM SQLDB...

and fro whatever reason I had to change it a little bit to work with IBM dashDB.

I had to change:

```
  $stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql, array('cursor' => DB2_SCROLLABLE));
```

to

```
   $stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql);
```